# Solution of irrational equations

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I need some help solving these equations:
       $ \sqrt{2x+1} - \sqrt{x+8} > 3$
and 
       $ \sqrt{3x^2 - 5a^2} = 2a - x$
Thank you in advance! :)

Comment: What have you tried already? On this site, we always want you to show your work before posting a problem.

Comment: Hello, and Welcome to Mathematics SE. I would like to bring to light the fact that this is not a homework-solving site, read the site's instructions to know more. Please produce your attempt and tell everyone where you were stuck. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

> $\sqrt{2x+1} - \sqrt{x+8} > 3$

Start by looking for the root(s) of the equation:
$$\sqrt{2x+1} - \sqrt{x+8} = 3$$
After squaring once:
$$(2x+1)+(x+8)-2\sqrt{(2x+1)(x+8)} = 9$$
Re-arrange, simplify and square again:
$$-2\sqrt{(2x+1)(x+8)} = 9-(2x+1)-(x+8)$$
$$-2\sqrt{(2x+1)(x+8)} = -3x$$
$$4(2x+1)(x+8) = 9x^2$$
This quadratic equation has roots $34 \pm 6 \sqrt{33}$ but only one of these satisfies the initial equation (the other one is introduced by the squaring operation), that is $34 + 6 \sqrt{33}$. Now check where the initial inequality is satisfied.

---

> $\sqrt{3x^2 - 5a^2} = 2a - x$

**Hint:** see above, start by squaring. You want to solve for $x$ or...?

Comment: Yes, I want to solve the second for x.. I know this is not a homework solving site, the problem is I can't remember at all how to solve them. Really appreciate your help! Thank you!

Comment: Are you able to finish from here? After squaring, the second question becomes an ordinary quadratic equation (though it contains the parameter $a$, of course).

Comment: Could you explain me shortly why $34 + 6\sqrt{33}$ is solution for the first? :(

Comment: Simplify $4(2x+1)(x+8) = 9x^2$ to bring into the standard form of a quadratic equation, you get $x^2-68 x-32$. You can [solve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_formula) this?

Comment: Yes, I understand that, but I asked why $34 + 6\sqrt{33}$ only and not the both or the other root.

Comment: For $x=34-6\sqrt{33}$, $\sqrt{2x+1} - \sqrt{x+8}< 0$ and so it cannot be $3$.

Answer (score 0):

The first is an "in"-equality, not an equation.  I will solve the second, $\sqrt{3x^2- 5a^2}= 2a- x$ first.

Get rid of the square root by **squaring** both sides: $3x^2- 5a^2= x^2- 4ax+ 4a^2$ so $2x^2+ 4ax= 9a^2$, $x^2+ 2ax= (9/2)a^2$.  Solve that quadratic equation by "completing the square" on the left. $x^2+ 2ax+ a^2= (x+ a)^2= (11/2)a^2$ so $x+ a= \pm\sqrt{11/2}a$.

One way to solve any inequality is to solve the associated **equation**: $\sqrt{2x+ 1}- \sqrt{x+ 8}= 3$.  Move the second radical to the right: $\sqrt{2x+1}= \sqrt{x+ 8}+ 3$.  Now square: $2x+ 1= x+ 8+ 6\sqrt{x+8}+ 9= x+ 17+ 6\sqrt{x+ 8}$.  Isolate that remaining radical- $6\sqrt{x+ 8}= x- 16$ and square.  $36(x+ 8)= x^2- 32x+ 256$ so $x^2- 68s- 32= 0$.  That is again a quadratic equation.  It might have no real roots, one real root, or two.  In any case, those roots, where the two sides are equal, **separate** ">" from "<".  To determine where this given inequality is satisfied, check the value at any one point inside each interval to determine whether ">" or "<" is correct.